# Return column name with coalesce

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select first not null value from several columns in my table.
Usually I would use

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) FROM table
```

but this time I don't need value, but name of column (or some specified text for every column) with first not null value.

An example:

Table:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
null | null | 3
null | 5    | 8
2    | null | 2
```

should return:

```
col3
col2
col1
```

Is there any way to do it with single SQL statement?

Note: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest to use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col1'
        WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col2'
        WHEN col3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'col3'
        ELSE NULL
   END
FROM table;
```

Comment: Right, it will probably be the best method. I forgot that I can use CASE with conditions. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use coalesce with a replace if all column is string.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(COALESCE(COL1||'COL1',COL2||'COL2',COL3||'COL3'),COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3),'')
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

If all column is number you could:

```
SELECT
    'COL'||CAST(COALESCE(COL1+1,COL2+2,COL3+3) - COALESCE(COL1,COL2,COL3) AS CHAR(1))
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: It would be good idea, but for varchar columns. It doesn't work for real-type values in columns.

Comment: @LidiaB. My second SQL can work for number values. If columns have different types, could convert them all to varchar, then can use the first SQL also. I know case statement is a good choice, but think different ways to solve a problem is really fun. Sometimes when you tuning a SQL more choice to be compared could be very useful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice edited answer before posting my comment becouse I didn't refresh this page before.

Comment: I just tried edited answer, but the problem is, that real column names aren't similar like examples are, and simply adding 'COL' isn't enougth. I also want to learn more and try different ways, so thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: As I mentioned in last comment, you could cast real values into varchar then use the first SQL, or you could use case statement translate 1,2,3 to column names.

Comment: Yes, there is some ways to do it as I want, but after some tests I think CASE will work better for my goals this time. But thank you.

Comment: One place this soliution would work better than the `WHEN..CASE` is when using in a calculated column. Only the `COALESCE` version would work as sub-queries are not allowed on the context of calculated columns .. at least with SQL Server this is the case